# VBA - Run time Error '91' Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, error-handling, runtime

I have created a file which I run multiple macros (for example 5). Everything works when I run all macros and I shared the file to a colleague (A) who said it works good. But when colleague (A) share to colleague (B), they encountered this error.

Can you please guide me on where I have been wrong?

```
Sub CaseListing()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook, lastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SR - Information").Range("A2:B1048576").Clear

   

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="https://*/All_Region_Case_List_CURRENT.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)

    lastRow = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    wbSource.Activate

    Range("B4:B" & lastRow & ",K4:K" & lastRow).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SR - Information").Range("A2")

   

    wbSource.Close

   

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SR - Information").Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row)

        .NumberFormat = "General"

        .Value = .Value

    End With

   

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SR - Information").Range("E1") = "<-- last refreshed on " & Now()

   

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

EMAIL

```
Public wsSR As Worksheet

Sub CreateEmail()

    Dim TempFilePath As String, TempFileName As String, FileExtStr As String, myFile As String

    Dim LastCell As Long, endR As Long

    Dim Fname As String, Lname As String, EmailAddress As String

    Dim ol As Outlook.Application

    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem

    Dim c1, c2 As Collection, msg As String, i As Variant

   

    Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook

    Set wsBW = wbMe.Sheets("B+W")

    Set wsSR = wbMe.Sheets("SR - Information")

    Set wsFinal = wbMe.Sheets("Report")

    Set wsCNA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C+N ")

    Set wsWebCNA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Web")

    Set c1 = New Collection

    Set c2 = New Collection

   

    pwd = "abc"

   

    With Application

        .ScreenUpdating = False

        .EnableEvents = False

    End With

 

    wsFinal.Unprotect pwd

   

    'Clear and Copy to the Final sheet

    wsFinal.Range("A5:V1048576").Clear

    LastCell = wsBW.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    wsBW.Range("A4:V" & LastCell).Copy

    wsFinal.Range("A4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

   

    Set wsSR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SR - Information")

    endR = wsSR.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   

    wsSR.Visible = False

    wsBW.Visible = False

    wsCNA.Visible = False

    wsWebCNA.Visible = False

   

    wsFinal.Range("A4:V" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Columns.AutoFit

   

    Set ol = New Outlook.Application

    Set mi = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)

   

    For Each cel In Sheets("SR - Information").Range("Q2:Q" & endR).Cells

        wsFinal.Activate

        wsFinal.Unprotect pwd

        Range("A4:V" & Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:=cel ', visibledropdown:=False

       

        Set IndxLookupRange = Sheets("SR - Information").Range("H:I")

        Set Matchlookuprange = Sheets("SR - Information").Range("H:H")

        cel.Offset(0, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.Index(IndxLookupRange, Application.Match(cel, Matchlookuprange, 0), 2), "-")

        EmailAddress = cel.Offset(0, 1)

       

        'Temporary file details

        TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"

        TempFileName = " Report - " & Format(Now, "mmmm dd, yyyy")

        FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", , 1)))

       

        If EmailAddress <> "-" Then

            For Each oAccount In ol.Session.Accounts

                If oAccount = "pqrs.abc@xyz.com" Then 'BD_Best_Practice

                    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

                    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

       

                    'Get the file ready - protection and hide

                    wsBW.protect pwd

                    wbMe.protect Password:=pwd, Structure:=True, Windows:=True

       

                    'Keep the desired sheet activate and save as temp file

                    wsFinal.Activate

                    wsFinal.protect pwd

                    wbMe.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

 

                    On Error Resume Next

                        With OutMail

                            .To = EmailAddress

                            .CC = ""

                            .BCC = ""

                            .Subject = " Report" '& Format(Now, "mmmm dd, yyyy") '" & Fname & "," & "<br> <br> "

                            .HTMLBody = "<BODY style='font-family:Calibri; font-size:11pt';>Hi, <br><br>" & _

                            "Please find the attached the Report. This report shows your Plan Sponsor's Enhanced Access user activity." & _

                             "<br> <br> Thank you, <br> xyz" & Range("F3") & "</font></BODY>"

                            .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

                            Set .SendUsingAccount = oAccount

                            '.Display

                            .send

                        End With

                    On Error GoTo 0

 

                    Set OutMail = Nothing

                    Set OutApp = Nothing

                End If

            Next oAccount

            'Delete the temp file

        Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

        Else

            c1.Add cel, CStr(cel)

            c2.Add cel, CStr(cel)

        End If

    Next cel

 

    wbMe.Unprotect Password:=pwd

    wsBW.Visible = True

    wsSR.Visible = True

    wsCNA.Visible = True

    wsWebCNA.Visible = True

   

    If c1.Count = 0 Then

        msg = "All Service Reps are matched!"

        Range("Q:R").Clear

        MsgBox msg

        Exit Sub

    Else

        msg = "Make sure to update the below list of Service Reps information manually!" & vbCrLf

        For i = 1 To c1.Count

            msg = msg & vbCrLf & c1.Item(i)

        Next i

    End If

    MsgBox msg '& vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Make sure Service Reps Details are updated manually!"

    wsSR.Range("Q:R").Clear

 

    wsBW.Select

   

    With Application

        .ScreenUpdating = True

        .EnableEvents = True

    End With

End Sub
```

IMPORTFILES

```
Public wbMe As Workbook

Public wsBW As Worksheet, wsSR As Worksheet, wsFinal As Worksheet

Public wsBoxi As Worksheet, wsWeb As Worksheet, wsWebCNA As Worksheet, wsNDR As Worksheet

Public pwd As Variant, domain As String

Public wsCNA As Worksheet

Sub ImportFiles()

'PURPOSE: 1 B and 1 W

    Dim f, fpath As String

 

    If MsgBox("Is it 2 B and 1 W?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

 

        Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook

        Set wsBW = wbMe.Sheets("B+W")

        Set wsSR = wbMe.Sheets("SR - Information")

        Set wsFinal = wbMe.Sheets("Report")

       

        pwd = "abc"

 

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 

        wsBW.Unprotect pwd

 

        If wsBW.AutoFilterMode = True Then wsBW.AutoFilterMode = False

 

        wsBW.Range("A4:Y1048576").Clear

        wbMe.Unprotect Password:=pwd ', Structure:=False, Windows:=False

 

        wsSR.Visible = True

        wsSR.Columns("P:R").Clear

 

        P = wbMe.Sheets.Count

        For m = P To 1 Step -1

            t = wbMe.Sheets(m).Name

            If t <> "B+W" And t <> "SR - Information" And t <> "Report" And t <> "C+ " And t <> "Web" And t <> "NDRs" Then

                Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                    wbMe.Sheets(m).Delete

                Application.DisplayAlerts = True

            End If

        Next m

 

        fpath = GetFolder & "\"

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        If fpath = "\" Then

            Exit Sub

        Else

            f = Dir(fpath)

            Do While Len(f) > 0

                Select Case Right(f, Len(f) - InStrRev(f, "."))

                    Case "xls", "xlsx", "csv"

                        OpenFile (fpath & f)

                End Select

                f = Dir

            Loop

 

            Set wsBoxi = wbMe.Sheets("Sheet1")

            Set wsWeb = wbMe.Sheets("GBA Access IDS")

 

            Call Merger

            Call Reorder_Columns

 

            'Apply Formats

            wsWeb.Range("A1").Copy

            wsBW.Range("A4:W4").PasteSpecial xlFormats

            wsBW.Rows("4:4").Columns.AutoFit

            Application.CutCopyMode = False

            Range("A4").Select

 

            P = wbMe.Sheets.Count

            For m = P To 1 Step -1

                t = wbMe.Sheets(m).Name

                If t <> "BOXI+WEB" And t <> "SR - Information" And t <> "Report" And t <> "C+N " And t <> "Web" And t <> "NDRs" Then

                    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

                        wbMe.Sheets(m).Delete

                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

                End If

            Next m

 

            wsBW.Range("$A$4:$U$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="C ", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="N "

 

            MsgBox "Merge Successful!"

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End If

    Else

        Call LoopAllFilesInFolder

    End If

End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String

    Dim f As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        .Title = "Select multiple Files"

        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path

        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo There

        f = .SelectedItems(1)

    End With

There:

    GetFolder = f

End Function

Private Sub OpenFile(filepath)

    Dim sh, wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filepath)

        'Debug.Print filepath

    For Each sh In wb.Sheets

        sh.Copy After:=wbMe.Sheets(wbMe.Sheets.Count)

    Next sh

    wb.Close False

End Sub

Private Sub Merger()

    Dim lastRow As Long

 

    wsBoxi.Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Delete

    wsWeb.Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Delete

 

    'Reorder BOXI columns

    wsBoxi.Columns("D:D").Cut

    wsBoxi.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

 

    Set IndexRange = wsBoxi.Range("A:G") 'BOXI

    Set MatchLookupRng = wsBoxi.Range("A:A")

 

    lastRow = wsWeb.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 

    wsWeb.Activate

    For Each AdID In wsWeb.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Cells

        Range("P" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 2), "-")    'Market Segment

        Range("Q" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 3), "-") 'Region code

        Range("R" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 4), "-") 'Cleint#

        Range("S" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 5), "-") 'Admin Access Level

        Range("T" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 6), "-") 'Admin Location Access

        Range("U" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 7), "-") 'Admin Access to all Locations

    Next AdID

 

    wsWeb.Range("P1").Value = "Market Segment"

    wsWeb.Range("Q1").Value = "Region Code"

    wsWeb.Range("R1").Value = "Client#"

    wsWeb.Range("S1").Value = "Admin Access Level"

    wsWeb.Range("T1").Value = "Admin Location Access"

    wsWeb.Range("U1").Value = "Admin Access to all Locations"

 

    wsWeb.Range("A1:U" & lastRow).Copy wsBW.Range("A4")

    wsBW.Range("A4:Y1048576").Font.Name = "Calibri"

    wsBW.Range("A4:Y1048576").Font.Size = 10

End Sub

 

Private Sub Reorder_Columns() 'Final Columns

    Dim ColumnOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer

    Dim Found As Range, counter As Integer

 

    ColumnOrder = Array("Market Segment", "Region Code", "Requestor Access ID", "Requestor Email", "Client#", "Transaction Type", _

    "Date Processed", "Admin First Name", "Admin Last Name", "Admin Language", "Admin Email", "Admin Access ID", "Admin Access Level", _

    "Admin Location Access", "Admin Access to all Locations", "Changed Admin First Name", "Changed Admin Last Name", "Changed Admin Language", _

    "Changed Admin Email", "Changed Admin Access Level", "Changed Admin Location Access")

    counter = 1

 

    wsBW.Activate

    For ndx = LBound(ColumnOrder) To UBound(ColumnOrder)

        Set Found = Rows("4:4").Find(ColumnOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not Found Is Nothing Then

            If Found.Column <> counter Then

                Found.EntireColumn.Cut

                Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

                Application.CutCopyMode = False

            End If

        counter = counter + 1

        End If

    Next ndx

    Call HighlightPlanAdmin

End Sub

Private Sub HighlightPlanAdmin()

    Dim ReqID As Range, nReqID As String, rReqID As String, tType As String, ntType As String

    wsBW.Activate

    For Each ReqID In Range("C5:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Cells

            rReqID = Trim(ReqID)

            tType = Trim(ReqID.Offset(0, 3)) '"Add Plan Admin"

            If tType = "Add Plan Admin" Then

                nReqID = Trim(ReqID.Offset(1, 0))  'Requestor ID next row

                If rReqID = nReqID Then

                    ntType = Trim(ReqID.Offset(1, 3))

                    If ntType <> "Add Plan Admin to OASIS." Then

                        ReqID.Offset(0, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 3

                    End If

                Else

                    ReqID.Offset(0, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 3

               End If

                If nReqID = "" Then

                    ntType = Trim(ReqID.Offset(1, 3))

                    If ntType = "" Then

                        ReqID.Offset(0, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 3

                    End If

                End If

            End If

    Next ReqID

End Sub

 

 

 

 

 

 

 

 

Sub LoopAllFilesInFolder()

'PURPOSE: 2 B and 1 W. To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform ...

 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   

    Set wsBW = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B+W")

    Set wsCNA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C+N ")

    Set wsWebCNA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Web")

    Set wsFinal = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")

    Set wsSR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SR - Information")

   

    wsBW.Unprotect "abc"

    If wsBW.AutoFilterMode = True Then wsBW.AutoFilterMode = False

   

    wsSR.Range("Q1:R1048576").Clear

    wsBW.Range("A4:Y1048576").Clear

    wsCNA.Range("A1:G1048576").Clear

    wsWebCNA.Range("A1:Z1048576").Clear

   

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"

        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"

        .Show

        

        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then

            xDirect = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"

            xFname = Dir(xDirect, 7)

            Do While xFname <> ""

                If InStr(1, xFname, "C ", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

                    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xDirect & xFname)

                    dendRow = wsCNA.UsedRange.Rows.Count

                    wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

                    If dendRow = 1 Then

                        wsCNA.Range("A" & dendRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    Else

                        wsCNA.Range("A" & dendRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    End If

                    wb.Close

                ElseIf InStr(1, xFname, "N ", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

                    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xDirect & xFname)

                    dendRow = wsCNA.UsedRange.Rows.Count

                    wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

                    wsCNA.Range("A" & dendRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    wb.Close

                ElseIf InStr(1, xFname, "Web", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

                    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xDirect & xFname)

                    wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

                    wsWebCNA.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    wb.Close

                End If

                xFname = Dir

            Loop

        End If

    End With

   

    wsCNA.Activate

    For Each cel In wsCNA.Range("A3:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Cells

        If InStr(1, cel, "Market Segment", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then

            cel.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete

            cel.EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Next cel

   

    Call MergerFolder

    Call Reorder_Columns_Folder

   

    'Apply Formats

   

    wsBW.Range("A4:W4").Font.Bold = True

    wsBW.Range("A4:W4").Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleSingle

    wsBW.Rows("4:4").Columns.AutoFit

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Range("A4").Select

   

    wsBW.Range("$A$4:$U$1048576").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Corporate Accounts", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="N "

   

    MsgBox "Merge Successful!"

   

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

 

Private Sub MergerFolder()

    Dim lastRow As Long

 

    wsCNA.Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Delete

    wsWebCNA.Rows("1:2").EntireRow.Delete

 

    'Reorder BOXI columns

    wsCNA.Columns("D:D").Cut

    wsCNA.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

 

    Set IndexRange = wsCNA.Range("A:G") 'BOXI

    Set MatchLookupRng = wsCNA.Range("A:A")

 

    lastRow = wsWebCNA.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 

    wsWebCNA.Activate

    For Each AdID In wsWebCNA.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Cells

        Range("P" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 2), "-") 'Market Segment

        Range("Q" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 3), "-") 'Region code

        Range("R" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 4), "-") 'Cleint#

        Range("S" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 5), "-") 'Admin Access Level

        Range("T" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 6), "-") 'Admin Location Access

        Range("U" & AdID.Row).Value = Application.IfError(Application.Index(IndexRange, Application.Match(AdID, MatchLookupRng, 0), 7), "-") 'Admin Access to all Locations

    Next AdID

 

    wsWebCNA.Range("P1").Value = "Market Segment"

    wsWebCNA.Range("Q1").Value = "Region Code"

    wsWebCNA.Range("R1").Value = "Client#"

    wsWebCNA.Range("S1").Value = "Admin Access Level"

    wsWebCNA.Range("T1").Value = "Admin Location Access"

    wsWebCNA.Range("U1").Value = "Admin Access to all Locations"

   

    wsWebCNA.Range("A1:U" & lastRow).Copy wsBW.Range("A4")

    wsBW.Range("A4:Y1048576").Font.Name = "Calibri"

    wsBW.Range("A4:Y1048576").Font.Size = 10

End Sub

Private Sub Reorder_Columns_Folder() 'Final Columns

    Dim ColumnOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer

    Dim Found As Range, counter As Integer

 

    ColumnOrder = Array("Market Segment", "Region Code", "Requestor Access ID", "Requestor Email", "Client#", "Transaction Type", _

    "Date Processed", "Admin First Name", "Admin Last Name", "Admin Language", "Admin Email", "Admin Access ID", "Admin Access Level", _

    "Admin Location Access", "Admin Access to all Locations", "Changed Admin First Name", "Changed Admin Last Name", "Changed Admin Language", _

    "Changed Admin Email", "Changed Admin Access Level", "Changed Admin Location Access")

    counter = 1

 

    wsBW.Activate

    For ndx = LBound(ColumnOrder) To UBound(ColumnOrder)

        Set Found = Rows("4:4").Find(ColumnOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not Found Is Nothing Then

            If Found.Column <> counter Then

                Found.EntireColumn.Cut

                Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

                Application.CutCopyMode = False

            End If

        counter = counter + 1

        End If

    Next ndx

    Call HighlightPlanAdmin_Folder

End Sub

Private Sub HighlightPlanAdmin_Folder()

    Dim ReqID As Range, nReqID As String, rReqID As String, tType As String, ntType As String

    wsBW.Activate

    For Each ReqID In Range("C5:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Cells

            ReqID.Select

            rReqID = Trim(ReqID)

            tType = Trim(ReqID.Offset(0, 3)) '"Add Plan Admin"

            If tType = "Add Plan Admin" Then

                nReqID = Trim(ReqID.Offset(1, 0))  'Requestor ID next row

                If rReqID = nReqID Then

                   ntType = Trim(ReqID.Offset(1, 3))

                    If ntType <> "Add Plan Admin to OASIS." Then

                        ReqID.Offset(0, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 3

                    End If

                Else

                    ReqID.Offset(0, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 3

                End If

                If nReqID = "" Then

                    ntType = Trim(ReqID.Offset(1, 3))

                    If ntType = "" Then

                        ReqID.Offset(0, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 3

                    End If

                End If

            End If

    Next ReqID

End Sub
```

SRMATCH

```
Public wsSR As Worksheet

Sub ServiceRepMatch()

   

    Set wsSR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SR - Information")

    Set wsBW = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B+W")

    Set SRLookupRng = wsSR.Range("A:B")

    Set macth = wsSR.Range("B1:B1048576")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   

    wsBW.Range("V4").Value = "Service Reps"

    For Each cel In wsBW.Range("E5:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Cells

        cel.Offset(0, 17) = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup(cel, SRLookupRng, 2, 0), "-")

    Next cel

   

    wsBW.Range("V4:V" & Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Row).Copy wsSR.Range("P1")

    wsSR.Select

    wsSR.Range("P1:P" & Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Row).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsSR.Range("Q1"), Unique:=True

    wsSR.Columns("P").Clear

   

    wsBW.Select

    MsgBox "DONE!"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

In nutshell, we first run IMPORTFILES to merge 2 reports it can either be 2 or 3 and perform some data manipluations. Secondly, CASELISTING is used to get the SR's client#. Third, we match the respective sales representatives through SRMATCH. Last, we use CREATEEMAIL to send individual emails for SR's their report and confidently message in the Body.

Comment: Code is required.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't set one of your object variables. Did you check those?

Comment: @braX If i've not used "SET" then why doesn't VBA throw an error to me or my other colleague? I was just posting the code, by then you closed the question?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've added the code. Please, do guide me in this issue.

Comment: Which line of which Sub is highlighted when the error occurs?

Comment: The person who encountered the error is no background with coding or anything related to IT (an Administrative assistant).  So, I've told to enable few option on Tools > References and check for workbook and sheet are not protected while running the macro.

Comment: There too much code posted here for anyone to have a hope of making a suggestion.  We need to know exactly where the problem is.

Comment: I am sorry about that. Definitely, I will try to connect with my colleague and run Step-by mode to witness the line of error.

Comment: Just a side note, but you don't need to space out every line of code... you have too much whitespace for this to be readable.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question fwiw. But definitely create a [mcve] with the exact error spot if you cannot solve it yourself after debugging on the aa's machine when running the code.

Comment: You shouldn't set the outlook object to nothing inside the loop - the next iteration will have no object. `Set OutApp = Nothing`

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your guidance on time. The issue is been resolved.

Comment: @BigBen I'm sorry about the white spaces, will remember it for next time.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Thank you for reopening the post. I'm aware about the minimal piece of code, since I was not able to figure out the issue as the code was running perfect on 3 systems, I thought this question was regarding the settings of Excel/VBA which I might have missed. Thanks again!

Comment: @KostasK. Thank you!